# Cannot install gunicorn on Ubuntu

Tags: django, ubuntu, gunicorn

I'm trying to install gunicorn in my virtual env, but get the following:

$ pip install gunicorn

```
Downloading/unpacking gunicorn
  Downloading gunicorn-0.14.2.tar.gz (203Kb): 203Kb downloaded 
  Running setup.py egg_info for package gunicorn

    warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'debian'
Installing collected packages: gunicorn   Found existing installation: gunicorn 0.14.2
  Uninstalling gunicorn:
    Successfully uninstalled gunicorn
  Running setup.py install for gunicorn

    warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'debian'
    Installing gunicorn_paster script to /home/aemdy/Documents/projects/reborn/env/bin
    Installing gunicorn script to /home/aemdy/Documents/projects/reborn/env/bin
    Installing gunicorn_django script to /home/aemdy/Documents/projects/reborn/env/bin
    Successfully installed gunicorn
    Cleaning up...
```

And when I use `python manage.py run_gunicorn` for django it says that this is unknown command. I have added gunicorn to INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: what is the output of `which python`?

Answer (score 2):

Warnings like that appear sometimes when installing apps. I believe it's related to cleanup pip tries to do, but it doesn't matter regardless. As the console output says "Successfully installed gunicorn". So no problems there.

With gunicorn installed, the only other requirement is adding `gunicorn` to `INSTALLED_APPS`. If you've done that as well, you're done. `run_gunicorn` will be available.

So, if it's *not* working, one of the following is in play:

1. Gunicorn isn't actually installed. However, you should get an error trying to reference in in `INSTALLED_APPS` in that scenario. Check your virtualenv's site-packages directory to ensure there's gunicorn folder there.
2. You installed Gunicorn in a different virtualenv. Again, you should be getting an error just as in #1. And, just as in #1, check to make sure it's actually in the proper virtualenv's site-packages directory
3. You don't have the virtualenv activated. However, same error as in #1 and #2 applies here.
4. You really don't have `gunicorn` in `INSTALLED_APPS` *or* a compiled version of settings.py is being used that doesn't have it in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Delete `settings.pyc` if it exists.

Comment: Also, it could be that you are overwriting your `INSTALLED_APPS` tuple if you have multiple settings files.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue. What I did was try to run the app using runserver which led to me seeing the hostname on the server was not set(and thus can't get an IP address). Once we fixed that issue the command worked again.

It is a little misleading to see:

```
Unknown command: 'run_gunicorn'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

when the hostname is not set...confusing I know but I hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score -2):

Did you remember to add gunicorn to your INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: It seems you haven't read all my post. I mentioned that I had done that.